# How does HDFS write to a disk on the data node

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I not an expert in how File Systems work, but this question can help me clear some vague concepts. How does HDFS write to the physical disk?

I understand HDFS runs on ext3 file system disks (typically). These file systems have a block size way less than the HDFS block size. So If I'm writing a ***logical*** HDFS block of 128 MB , the disk could be storing it smaller ***physical*** blocks.

Does HDFS ensure these physical blocks are contiguous? (Contiguous blocks increase FS throughput as it minimizes seek time)?

How does HDFS deliver high throughput?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know HDFS does not care about the physical file system on which it is running. I installed Hadoop on several different file system, for example I also used solaris ZFS.

The blocks of hadoop/hdfs are written as ordinary files on each datanode. The namenode takes to role of inodes or FAT in the OS filesystems. HDFS is a layer above the physical filesystem on each datanode.

You can list the stored blocks in your hadoop/hdfs filesystem just by listing directory content on the data node:

```
/srv/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-1458088587-192.168.1.51-1394008575227/current/finalized$ ls -alh ./blk_1073741838
-rw-r--r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 1.4M Mar  6 10:55 ./blk_1073741838
```

Comment: The HDFS seems to be more logical than physical. If HDFS doesn't influence how the raw data is stored on the disk (coniguously or sequentially) then doesn't the disk bound ot have fragmentation and eventually deteriorate the I/O performance. For example if we are storing 150 MB of data for a HDFS block size of 128 MB. Even if a songle block is stored contiguously the 22 MB might lad to fragmentation when you delete the file.

Comment: For me HDFS is another storage layer on top of the conventional storage layer of each data node server. The important thing of HDFS is that it scales well if you increase the amount of stored data! Keep in mind that one huge file stored in HDFS is spread acress several data nodes anyway. Per default every single block is replicated three time to other datanodes to get tolerance of complete failure of a whole data node.